How to build ROS packages on Mac silicon?
I got the error trying to build the package that I created using the instruction available on http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/ RosWiki
I am also trying to understand the folder structure and I am a noob trying to get into this field of robotics and everyone points to ROS and this is getting frustrating because I can't create a simple package and get to scripting.
I am running M3 Mac, let me know if you need anything else from me to help me troubleshoot this. I installed ROS using conda following instruction on this website:
https://robostack.github.io/GettingStarted.html
Let me know if I am doing something wrong following basic instructions. Please be kind, life is hard already, thanks.
Recreating issue:
(ros_env) ➜  ros2_ws rm -rf ./*
zsh: sure you want to delete all 4 files in /Users/someone/Desktop/Projects/ROS-Basics/ros2_ws/. [yn]? y
(ros_env) ➜  ros2_ws ls
(ros_env) ➜  ros2_ws mkdir src
(ros_env) ➜  ros2_ws src
(ros_env) ➜  src ros2 pkg create --build-type ament_python basics --dependencies rclpy
going to create a new package
package name: basics
destination directory: /Users/someone/Desktop/Projects/ROS-Basics/ros2_ws/src
package format: 3
version: 0.0.0
description: TODO: Package description
maintainer: []
licenses: ['TODO: License declaration']
build type: ament_python
dependencies: ['rclpy']
creating folder ./basics
creating ./basics/package.xml
creating source folder
creating folder ./basics/basics
creating ./basics/setup.py
creating ./basics/setup.cfg
creating folder ./basics/resource
creating ./basics/resource/basics
creating ./basics/basics/__init__.py
creating folder ./basics/test
creating ./basics/test/test_copyright.py
creating ./basics/test/test_flake8.py
creating ./basics/test/test_pep257.py

[WARNING]: Unknown license 'TODO: License declaration'.  This has been set in the package.xml, but no LICENSE file has been created.
It is recommended to use one of the ament license identitifers:
Apache-2.0
BSL-1.0
BSD-2.0
BSD-2-Clause
BSD-3-Clause
GPL-3.0-only
LGPL-3.0-only
MIT
MIT-0
(ros_env) ➜  src ..
(ros_env) ➜  ros2_ws ..
(ros_env) ➜  ROS-Basics colcon build          
Starting >>> basics  
[0.216s] WARNING:colcon.colcon_core.prefix_path.colcon:The path '/Users/someone/Desktop/Projects/ROS-Basics/ros2_ws/install' in the environment variable COLCON_PREFIX_PATH doesn't exist
--- stderr: basics                   
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python3.12/site-packages/colcon_core/executor/__init__.py", line 91, in __call__
    rc = await self.task(*args, **kwargs)
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python3.12/site-packages/colcon_core/task/__init__.py", line 93, in __call__
    return await task_method(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python3.12/site-packages/colcon_ros/task/ament_python/build.py", line 102, in build
    return await extension.build(additional_hooks=additional_hooks)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python3.12/site-packages/colcon_core/task/python/build.py", line 90, in build
    available_commands = await self._get_available_commands(
                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python3.12/site-packages/colcon_core/task/python/build.py", line 188, in _get_available_commands
    output = await check_output(
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python3.12/site-packages/colcon_core/subprocess.py", line 129, in check_output
    assert not rc, f'Expected {args} to pass: {stderr_data}'
           ^^^^^^
AssertionError: Expected ['/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/bin/python3', '-W', 'ignore:setup.py install is deprecated', 'setup.py', '--help-commands'] to pass: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/someone/Desktop/Projects/ROS-Basics/ros2_ws/src/basics/setup.py", line 5, in <module>
    setup(
  File "/opt/anaconda3/envs/ros_env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/__init__.py", line 104, in setup
    return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/opt/anaconda3/envs/ros_env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/core.py", line 171, in setup
    ok = dist.parse_command_line()
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/opt/anaconda3/envs/ros_env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/dist.py", line 473, in parse_command_line
    if self.handle_display_options(option_order):
       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/opt/anaconda3/envs/ros_env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 943, in handle_display_options
    return _Distribution.handle_display_options(self, option_order)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/opt/anaconda3/envs/ros_env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/dist.py", line 688, in handle_display_options
    self.print_commands()
  File "/opt/anaconda3/envs/ros_env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 722, in print_commands
    cmdclass = ep.load()
               ^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python3.12/importlib/metadata/__init__.py", line 205, in load
    module = import_module(match.group('module'))
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python3.12/importlib/__init__.py", line 90, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1387, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1360, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1310, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 488, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1387, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1360, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1331, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 935, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 995, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 488, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python3.12/site-packages/nose/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from nose.core import collector, main, run, run_exit, runmodule
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python3.12/site-packages/nose/core.py", line 12, in <module>
    from nose.loader import defaultTestLoader
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python3.12/site-packages/nose/loader.py", line 21, in <module>
    from nose.importer import Importer, add_path, remove_path
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python3.12/site-packages/nose/importer.py", line 12, in <module>
    from imp import find_module, load_module, acquire_lock, release_lock
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'imp'

---
Failed   <<< basics [0.40s, exited with code 1]

Summary: 0 packages finished [0.48s]
  1 package failed: basics
  1 package had stderr output: basics
Expected ['/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/bin/python3', '-W', 'ignore:setup.py install is deprecated', 'setup.py', '--help-commands'] to pass: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/someone/Desktop/Projects/ROS-Basics/ros2_ws/src/basics/setup.py", line 5, in <module>
    setup(
  File "/opt/anaconda3/envs/ros_env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/__init__.py", line 104, in setup
    return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/opt/anaconda3/envs/ros_env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/core.py", line 171, in setup
    ok = dist.parse_command_line()
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/opt/anaconda3/envs/ros_env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/dist.py", line 473, in parse_command_line
    if self.handle_display_options(option_order):
       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/opt/anaconda3/envs/ros_env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 943, in handle_display_options
    return _Distribution.handle_display_options(self, option_order)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/opt/anaconda3/envs/ros_env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/dist.py", line 688, in handle_display_options
    self.print_commands()
  File "/opt/anaconda3/envs/ros_env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 722, in print_commands
    cmdclass = ep.load()
               ^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python3.12/importlib/metadata/__init__.py", line 205, in load
    module = import_module(match.group('module'))
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python3.12/importlib/__init__.py", line 90, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1387, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1360, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1310, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 488, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1387, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1360, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1331, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 935, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 995, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 488, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python3.12/site-packages/nose/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from nose.core import collector, main, run, run_exit, runmodule
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python3.12/site-packages/nose/core.py", line 12, in <module>
    from nose.loader import defaultTestLoader
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python3.12/site-packages/nose/loader.py", line 21, in <module>
    from nose.importer import Importer, add_path, remove_path
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python3.12/site-packages/nose/importer.py", line 12, in <module>
    from imp import find_module, load_module, acquire_lock, release_lock
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'imp'
(ros_env) ➜  ros2_ws 
(ros_env) ➜  ros2_ws source install/setup.zsh
(ros_env) ➜  ros2_ws rosdep check --all
All system dependencies have been satisfied
(ros_env) ➜  ros2_ws python3 -m pip install setuptools 
Requirement already satisfied: setuptools in /opt/anaconda3/envs/ros_env/lib/python3.9/site-packages (69.5.1)
(ros_env) ➜  ros2_ws 


Edit:
Adding what I found online:
https://github.com/colcon/colcon-core/issues/584
https://www.reddit.com/r/ROS/comments/17casm6/colcon_build_error_on_python_packages/
Building example library of ROS 2
https://get-help.theconstruct.ai/t/malformed-launch-argument-start-wall-following-launch-py/24454

It might be worth quoting the relevant parts of the links (in your "edit") (or stating why those links are relevant) as people are unlikely to want to click through all of the links in order to understand your problem. You are much more likely to get a good answer if all of the info is in the post. Keep the links in place as reference, just include the relevant sections from those links.
